# (htaccess) How to allow access to a page only from within website?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have this URL in a Wordpress installation:

www.example.com/protected-page/

and I want it to only be accessible from links within my website, so only if you click on a link to it on my website. Everyone else (direct access from bookmark or link on another website) should be redirected to www.example.com, my domain.

I tried finding HTTP_REFERER code for .htaccess, but being a newbie isn't helpful.

Can you help me write a .htacess rule that will do this? Please.

This is what I got so far, doesn't work...

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !www.example.com [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^/restricted-page$ /redirected-page [R,NC]

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html  The top example is pretty much what you want

Comment: thanks for your reply. but that example is not what I want. I need a rule for only 1 page, not for the whole website. other pages from the website can be accesed from anywhere, I need to protect only one page.

Comment: "pretty much" - change `\.(gif|jpg|png)$` to `^yourpage$`

Comment: ok, I did it and it doesn't work... i updated the post.

Comment: you jsut need the restricted-page part, also that will show a 403 page, Its the second one you want, redirect to a page

Comment: i tried that one, too, it doesn't work. i updated my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/restricted-page - [F]
```

Comment: no, I've tried it now... it does nothing, it still allows me to see the restricted page.